# Show Printable page behaviour

Tags: jsf-2.2, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am developing a web application using Oracle ADF. I need to print a graph from our web application. For this am using **show printable page behaviour**. Actually I have a page with graph.

I added show Printable behaviour as menu as shown below

[image]

when I press Printable View button It is showing entire page as printable view as show below

[image]

But I need only graph should be show in printable view as below

[image]

How do I achieve this.?? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rendered property on components to prevent printing them:

```
 <af:outputText value="Do not Print Me" rendered="#{adfFacesContext.outputMode!= 'printable'}" id="ot11"/>
```

More info, here:
https://blogs.oracle.com/jdevotnharvest/entry/how_to_hide_or_show

Comment: florinmarcus Thanks a lot for your time. Actually am working on  this. I definitely vote for answers if they are working. Otherwise I will update the status through comment as my other question. So I ll update the status for this answer also. Sorry for the delay. I definitely update the status.

Comment: florinmarcus thank you very much. It is working. Thank you very much.... Thanks a lot.